# local variable not used when declaring an editText java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

Hi im having trouble establishing the problem with my code. it compiles just fine but when launched and accessed in my app, the app crashes. when i edit the editText line of code the app runs completely fine. The error is get is that the local variable is never used. I have done and looked all i can to see similar topics regarding my issue but haven't found anything that could help. Here is the following code I am working on:

```
public class AddNewTask extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText name, date;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_tasks);

    // set up click listeners for all the buttons
    View new_task_priority_button = 
                findViewById(R.id.new_task_priority_button);
    new_task_priority_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    View addTask_button = findViewById(R.id.addTask_button);
    addTask_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    View cancel_button = findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    cancel_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    View View_button = findViewById(R.id.View_button);
    View_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    final EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.task_name);
    final EditText date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date); 
}

public void onClick(View arg0){

    switch (arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.new_task_priority_button:
        OpenPriorityDialog();
        break;          
    case R.id.View_button:
        break;      
    case R.id.addTask_button:
        break;          
    case R.id.cancel_button:
        break;
    }
}
```

These lines cause my program to crash when accesed from my main menu, sqlName and sqlDate comes up with an error message saying local variable never used but I have declared them above.

```
   final EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.task_name);
   final EditText date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
```

If anyone could help me out or point me in the right direction I would be very grateful

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have the variables declared in 2 locations. Try this:

```
final EditText name, date;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       //Keep same stuff here

      name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.task_name);
      date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.date);
}
```

This will work because final variables are allowed to be set one time, and the onCreate() is only called one time. There are other solutions as well, but essentially you were locally declaring a variable, where it was already declared class-wide. So it ignored the declaration from the class, and just created it's own local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you declared the task_name and task_name as EditText in layout xml files? If you haven't declared as EditText, you will get a classcast exception.